# Defining Attributes as Mandatory in the XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

Need help on defining attribute as mandatory field in the XSD so that it will help for the Error handling part to raise the exception,

```
XSD:
===
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Req_Pay">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Package" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Payment" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Line" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="LinePaymentAmount" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                          <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="Agg" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="ConNum" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="PayId" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="Cur" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="Memo" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="PackagePaymentAmount" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="PackagePaymentQuantity" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**The Hierarchical representation of the above XSD can be seen as below,**

```
Req_Pay (Element)
   - Package (Element)
      - PackagePaymentAmount (attribute 1)
      - PackagePaymentQuantity (attribute 2) **(Mandatory Field)**
      - Payment (Element)
          - PayId (attribute 1)
          - Cur (attribute 2) **(Mandatory Field)**
          - Memo (attribute 3) **(Mandatory Field)**
          - Line (Element)
            - LinePaymentAmount (Element) **(Mandatory Field)**
            - Agg (attribute 1) 
            - ConNum (attribute 2)  **(Mandatory Field)**
```

```
**Please find the below input data which will be passed to the above created XSD**,

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Req_Pay>
   <Package PackagePaymentAmount="452.88" PackagePaymentQuantity="200.00">
      <Payment PayId="1000000-0001" Cur="USD" Memo="AK005-18308-20222">
         <Line Agg="yes" ConNum="MED" >
            <LinePaymentAmount>226.4400</LinePaymentAmount>
         </Line>
         <Line Agg="yes" ConNum="FFS" >
            <LinePaymentAmount>226.4400</LinePaymentAmount>
         </Line>
      </Payment>
   </Package>
</Req_Pay>
```

I am able to define **LinePaymentAmount** as mandatory element and is working perfectly (during missing field value the error is thrown and exception is raised for the missing field value), but I am not able to define Attributes as mandatory.
I have already defined **use=required** for the mandatory attributes, but it is not working and I also tried the blog "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690949/element-mandatory-attribute-declaration-in-xsd-schema#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20attribute%20as,simpleType%20%2F%3E%20and%20use%20that.&text=I%20am%20not%20certain%20what,that%20is%20not%20yet%20known." but still its not working.

Can you please help to let me know how to define mandatory attributes fields in the XSD.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] where you show the breakdown of your expectations via a document that you think should be invalid because it is missing required attributes yet is in fact validating successfully. What you've posted so far does not demonstrate any problem as Martin Honnen [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74841348/290085) in his answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how your sample input looks and which parser you use and how it fails but certainly when I use your schema as posted, let e.g. oXygen XML editor generate a sample file and remove one or two of the required attributes to get e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Req_Pay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample1.xsd">
    <Package PackagePaymentAmount="PackagePaymentAmount0" PackagePaymentQuantity="PackagePaymentQuantity0">
        <Payment PayId="PayId0" Cur="Cur0" Memo="Memo0">
            <Line Agg="Agg0" ConNum="ConNum0">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount0</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
            <Line Agg="Agg1" ConNum="ConNum1">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount1</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
        </Payment>
        <Payment PayId="PayId1" Cur="Cur1" Memo="Memo1">
            <Line Agg="Agg2">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount2</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
            <Line Agg="Agg3" ConNum="ConNum3">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount3</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
        </Payment>
    </Package>
    <Package PackagePaymentAmount="PackagePaymentAmount1" PackagePaymentQuantity="PackagePaymentQuantity1">
        <Payment PayId="PayId2" Cur="Cur2" Memo="Memo2">
            <Line Agg="Agg4" ConNum="ConNum4">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount4</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
            <Line 
                ConNum="ConNum5">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount5</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
        </Payment>
        <Payment PayId="PayId3" Cur="Cur3" Memo="Memo3">
            <Line Agg="Agg6" ConNum="ConNum6">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount6</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
            <Line Agg="Agg7" ConNum="ConNum7">
                <LinePaymentAmount>LinePaymentAmount7</LinePaymentAmount>
            </Line>
        </Payment>
    </Package>
</Req_Pay>
```

I get two validation errors

```
Description: Attribute 'ConNum' must appear on element 'Line'.
Start location: 14:14
End location: 14:18

Description: Attribute 'Agg' must appear on element 'Line'.
Start location: 27:14
End location: 27:18
```

from Apache Xerces that oXygen uses as the default validating parser.

Comment: Hi Martin,

Thanks a lot for your response.

I have added the Input XML against the XSD. We will receive the xsd in that format

Comment: @Nikita, that shown XML sample seems to perfectly valid, having all required attributes.

Comment: Hi Martin,

Yes, but incase if value is not coming for the mandatory Attribute in the incoming payload then it should raise exception. As told I am able to achieve this for the mandatory Element file LinePaymentAmount and for this I have defined structure, but for attribute I need to define similar kind of structure but its notworking.
I have already added an URL where they have defined structure for attribute, I tried with similar thing for attribute but its not working.

Comment: @Nikita: Post XML that you think should be invalid yet is validating contrary to your expectations.  Your verbal attempts to describe what's wrong are too imprecise to convey the problem.

Comment: @Nikita, and also explain which tool/which parser you use that fails to indicate the validation problem with required attributes.

Comment: This is SAP integration tool, and it make use of SAXParseException.
below is the error exception thrown for the Mandatory element field "LinePaymentAmount" when value is missing for reference,same we need for the attribute,

Error:
======
Validation failed for: /xsd/CheckRequest.xsd
errors: [
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content "" of element <LinePaymentAmount> does not match the required simple type. Value "" contravenes the minLength facet "1" of the type of element LinePaymentAmount, Line : 5, Column : 33
]. Exchange[ID-93d7269a-eb61-4ab0-52c0-d1bc-1671146136067-79-4].

Comment: Is there is a tag for that SAP tool, add that tag. Or contact their support, I don't think anyone on Stack Overflow not familiar with the product can tell why you don't get an error if a required attribute is missing.